# Getting info from PHP file - Not in same Directory

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm completely baffled with this. I've tried seemingly everything, and nothing has worked so far!

Basically, I have a PHP script which does some stuff and will feed out a number. Now, this PHP file is being hosted on my server and I need to extract that number from the PHP file through a HTML script which I can put anywhere.

This script works fine when both the PHP file, and the HTML file (which contains this script) are in the same directory:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("index.php",function(data){
      document.write(data);
    });
  });
</script>
```

However, as the PHP script will be uploaded on a server, I need to be able to get the number which is displayed on the PHP script from wherever I put this code. So basically, I need to be able to use this code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("http://www.myserver.com/scripts/index.php",function(data){
      document.write(data);
    });
  });
</script>
```

But I am really unsure as to why it is not working when it isn't in the same directory. I'm not looking to overcomplicate this, and just need a small snippet of code that I can use to collect the number which is fed from that PHP script. Please note that I cannot put these files in the same directory as I'm going to be using this code to feed the number onto a site-editor made website.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your console for javascript errors? Or have you checked to see what the value of `data` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requests are getting blocked because of the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), your only choice is to use the same domain or [enable cors](http://enable-cors.org/).

So as long as your page AND php file are both placed under www.myserver.com, it will work.

JSONP Examples can be found [here](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/) and [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/)

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://www.myserver.com/php/file.php",
jsonp: "callback",
dataType: "jsonp",
success: function( response ) {
    console.log( response ); // server response
}
```

});

Comment: After looking slightly more into this, I found that JSONP can get round the Same-origin thing (I didn't know this existed till now, thanks!). Is it possible to get the information from the PHP script into a JSON one so I can collect the number that way?

Comment: @Timur: bye, I'll delete my answer

Comment: @LegacyP7 you can always encode your php file output (no need for new file) in json format -> echo json_encode($data);

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a go and if I am unsuccessful, how do I go about using "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". As this seems to be able to also get around the problem, how do I include it, and where do I put it?

Comment: @LegacyP7 the best place would be apache config (see the link i posted) or you can just modify your php file -> put this first thing after opening tag ->  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");